# Can i receive implicit broadcasts in the background using a broadcast receiver without using a service?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Because implicit broadcast intents can not be registered in the manifest, i have context registered my receiver to check for internet connectivity. But i want my app to detect these changes when the app is in the background. Is there any way to do that without using a service?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the reason that why do you want to check internet connectivity while app is in background?

Comment: I want my app to listen to these implicit broadcasts, even if the app is not running, so as to do some work as soon as internet connectivity is available.

Comment: ok well you can do you. what you want  to listen notifications  or sms  or calls or anything else?